# Formatting a Date from an Excel Sheet

Tags: java, excel

I am reading a date column from an Excel Sheet in my Java program via Apache POI that returns the string `Fri Jan 16 00:00:00 EST 2015`. I need to format this string to `01/16/2016`.

I try the following using the `SimpleDateFormat` to parse the String to a `Date` Object, then back to the formatted `String` I need

```
String inputDate = excelData.get(20).toString(); // Returns Fri Jan 16 00:00:00 EST 201
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(inputDate);
String outputDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(date);
```

However the following is returned when trying to parse `inputDate`

```
Unparseable date: "Fri Jan 16 00:00:00 EST 2015"
```

Is my `inputDate` unreadable or am I missing something here? I've also thought of formatting the cell itself to the proper date format instead - thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is on this line:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat(**"MM/dd/yyyy"**).parse(inputDate);
```

The date format you've described looks more like:
"DDD MMM DD HH:mm:ss tz yyyy" or something like that.

Use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html to find the right formatter in order to read the date.

The output looks fine, given you can read the input string format as the right format into a Date.

Answer (score 1):

Your code tells `SimpleDateFormat` to use `MM/dd/yyyy` format to PARSE the date, so of course it can't work, since this is not the format of the string you get.

The POI FAQ at https://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N1008D gives a snippet of code to read a date:

```
case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
     double d = cell.getNumericCellValue();
     // test if a date!
     if (HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
       // format in form of M/D/YY
       cal.setTime(HSSFDateUtil.getJavaDate(d));
       cellText =
         (String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR))).substring(2);
       cellText = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1 + "/" +
                  cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" +
                  cellText;
     }
```

Have you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse(inputDate);
```

to

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM DD HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy").parse(inputDate);
```

---

```
zzz   Time zone              EST
EEE   Day name in week       Tuesday
MMM   Month in year          July
```

**Reference:** [SimpleDateFormat doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: `DD` in `"EEE MMM DD HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"` needs to be replaced with `dd` as it is meant to be the day of the month not of the year.